# Error: no suitable method found for hadoopFile(String,Class<HibInputFormat>,Class<HipiImageHeader>,Class<FloatImage>)

Tags: apache-spark, image-processing, hipi

I am using HIPI with spark 2.0.2 to do image processing.

And I want to load the images stored in the HipiImageBundle(.hib) on HDFS in the RDD.

So I use the hadoopfile() method in order to create an RDD as shown in the code below :

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
          .builder()
          .appName("AppName")
          .getOrCreate();
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());
JavaPairRDD<HipiImageHeader,FloatImage> floatimages = jsc.hadoopFile("hdfs://cluster-1-m/user/ibtissam/image.hib",HibInputFormat.class,HipiImageHeader.class,FloatImage.class);
```

Then, I get this error :

> error: no suitable method found for
>   hadoopFile(String,Class,Class,Class)

Have you any idea about how i can resolve this ?

Ps : I use :

- Java
- Spark 2.0.2